# Running into memory issues with Data.Sequence on a manageably sized dataset

Tags: haskell, memory-management, sequence

**TL;DR:** I'm working on a piece of code which generates a (long) array of numbers.  I'm able to generate this array, convert it to a `List` and then calculate the maximum (using a strict left fold).  BUT, I run into memory issues when I try to convert the list to a `Sequence` prior to calculating the maximum.  This is quite counter-intuitive to me.

My question: Why is this happening and what is the correct approach for converting the data to a `Sequence` structure?

**Background:**
I'm working on a problem which I've chosen to tackle in using three steps (below).

*Note: I'm intentionally keeping the problem statement vague so this post doesn't serve as a hint.

Anyways, my proposed approach:

(i) First, generate a long list of integers, namely, the number of factors for each integer from 1 to 100 million (NOT the factors themselves, just the number of factors)

(ii) second, convert this list into a Sequence.

(iii) lastly, use an efficient sliding window maximum algorithm to calc my answer (this step requires dequeue operations, hence the need for a Sequence)

(Again, the specifics of the problem aren't that relevant as I'm just curious as to why I'm running into this particular issue in the first place.)

**What I've done so far?**
Step 1 was fairly straightforward - see output below (full code is included at the bottom).  I just bruteforce a sieve using an Unboxed Array and the `accumArray` function, nothing fancy.  Note: I've used this same algorithm to solve a number of other such problems so I'm reasonably confident that it's giving the right answer.

For the purposes of showing execution time / memory-usage stats, I've (admittedly arbitrarily) chosen to calculate the maximum element in the resulting array - the idea is simply to use a function which forces construction of all elements of the Array, thereby ensuring that we see meaningful stats for exec time / memory-usage.

The following `main` function...

```
main = print $ maximum' $ elems (sieve (10^8))
```

...results in the following (i.e., it says that the number below 100 million with the most divisors has a total of 768 divisors):

```
Linking maxdivSO ...
768 
33.73s user 70.80s system 99% cpu 1:44.62 total

 344,214,504,640 bytes allocated in the heap
  58,471,497,320 bytes copied during GC
     200,062,352 bytes maximum residency (298 sample(s))
       3,413,824 bytes maximum slop
             386 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

 %GC     time      24.7%  (30.5% elapsed)
```

**The problem**

It seems like we can accomplish the first step without breaking a sweat since I've allocated a total of 5gb to my VirtualBox and the above code uses <400mb (as reference, I've seen programs execute successfully and report using 3gb+ of total memory).  In other words, it seems like we've accomplished Step 1 with plenty of headroom.

So I'm a bit surprised as to why the following version of the `main` function fails.  We attempt to perform the same calculation of the maximum but after converting the list of integers to a Sequence.  The following code...

```
main = print $ maximum' $ fromList $ elems (sieve (10^8))
```

...results in the following:

```
Linking maxdivSO ...
maxdivSO: out of memory (requested 2097152 bytes)
  39.48s user 76.35s system 99% cpu 1:56.03 total
```

**My question: Why does the algorithm (as currently written) run out of memory if we try to convert the list to a Sequence?  And how might I go about successfully converting this list into a Sequence?"**

(I'm not one to stubbornly stick to brute-force for these types of problems - but I have a strong suspicion that this particular issue is due to my not being able to reason well about evaluation.)

---

The code itself:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import Data.Word (Word32, Word16)
import Data.Foldable (Foldable, foldl')

import Data.Array.Unboxed (UArray, accumArray, elems)
import Data.Sequence (fromList)

main :: IO ()
main = print $ maximum' $ elems (sieve (10^8))                -- <-- works
--main = print $ maximum' $ fromList $ elems (sieve (10^8))   -- <-- doesn't work

maximum' :: (Foldable t, Ord a, Num a) => t a -> a
maximum' = foldl' (\x acc -> if x > acc then x else acc) 0

sieve :: Int -> UArray Word32 Word16
sieve u' = accumArray (+) 2 (1,u) ( (1,-1) : factors )
  where
    u = fromIntegral u'
    cap = floor $ sqrt (fromIntegral u) :: Word32
    factors = [ (i*d,j) | d <- [2..cap]
                        , i <- [2..(u `quot` d)]
                        , d <= i, let j = if i == d then 1 else 2
              ]
```

Comment: Well, I was looking at this, then I got as far as the combination of `NoImplicitPrelude` and `import CorePrelude`, and realized this code could be doing *anything*. I just can't tell. Can you provide an example of the problem without them?

Comment: Your `maximum` will work for any `Foldable`, so why not just use the list instead of converting to `Seq`? In fact, why not just write a `foldl'` for folding an array and avoid both conversions?

Comment: @Carl: updated code is attached, no longer using CorePrelude.  (Just as an FYI: I don't think it's an uncommon package to use: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/basic-prelude-0.3.0.0)

Comment: @DavidYoung Poor choice of words on my part.  What happens in step 3 is not accomplished using a fold function.  I need to calculate the sliding window maximum and, in order to do so, I have a function which takes advantage of Sequence's O(1) deque operations that allow me to do it in O(N) time with a single pass, which is why Lists/Arrays/etc. wouldn't work.

Comment: I don't understand why you would need or want a sliding window to calculate a maximum. What you display is a simple fold. If you want to use a `Seq` to represent a window, use it for the window—not the whole thing. If all you really need is a queue, a simple Banker's queue will be about twice as fast as `Seq`, which is a more complex general-purpose structure.

Comment: @dfeuer BankersDequeue is not sufficiently strict (profiling shows that it uses 5x as much memory as Seq for the same task, atleast when using the Data.Dequeue package).  The eventual goal is to calc the sum of the sliding window maximums with a window size of 100,000 elements.  My sliding window function only attempts to convert the window itself into a Seq and it still runs into this same issue...

Comment: @DipakC, you still have not explained why a sliding window is appropriate at all. I was not talking about `Data.Deque`, but rather about Banker's queues in general (they can be tweaked various ways). Note that strict left folds for `Seq` are not optimized at all (I meant to look into that, but missed it for the upcoming version) so you may be better off taking the maximum by hand, or converting to a list and using a NOINLINE copy of `id` to prevent undesirable fusion.

Comment: @dfeuer The problem asks for the sum of the maximum of all windows having a width of 100,000 elements, hence the sliding window...  In other words, we have a list of 100,000,000 elements and we want to calculate the sum of the maximums of all 99,900,001 windows, each of which has 100,000 elements.  I assumed (possibly naively?) that it's probably best to get the maxima using an algorithm that takes O(n) time and O(k) space (n = total elements, k = window width), e.g., like the one described here: http://softwarelearner.blogspot.com/2011/04/minima-in-sliding-window.html

Comment: Now I see. I did not understand the problem properly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason for this is that to get the first element of of a sequence requires the full sequence to be constructed in memory (since the internal representation of the sequence is a tree). In the list case `elems` yields the elements lazily.

Rather than turning the full array into a sequence, why not make the sequence only as long as your sliding window?

Comment: My sliding window algorithm is currently set up so that we only generate Sequences for the two dequeues used to keep track of the window (one to hold the window, one to hold a list of local maxima).  In other words, the sliding window algorithm (which also fails due to memory issues) processes a large list while keeping track of two short sequences that are at most as wide as the window itself...  Regarding your last suggestion: do you know of any links that discuss implementing an efficient sliding window algorithm without the use of dequeues?  That might in fact be the best approach...

Comment: @DipakC Actually I don't. Removing that part of my answer.

Comment: Your algorithm doesn't track two short sequences that I see. Rather `maximum' $ fromList $ elems (sieve (10^8)` seems like it takes the maximum of the entire sequence? I see no sliding window at all. Perhaps you pasted the wrong code?